# MEMS Oscillator Simulation in LTSPICE

Tags: oscillator, feedback, oscillation, mems, resonator

The MEMS oscillator topology i simulate is below
[image]

fig1: Oscillator schematic
Source: A Tunable-Gain Transimpedance Amplifier for CMOS-MEMS Resonators Characterization

Below is mine, the resonator i am using is around 520 [kHz]

[image]

fig2: LTSpice simulation command

[image]

fig3: Oscillator circuit with MEMS equavilent model, sustaining amplifier, and a pulse to start oscillate

[image]

fig4: Vo

But the output (Vo) is not showing any sign for oscillatung.

In the best of my knowledge, the sustaining amplifier must have a gain greater than rm of resonator in [dBohn] and a phase shift of 0 [deg] which from my below is also meet
[image]

fig5: Sustaining amplifier or so called TIA simulation circuit

[image]

fig5: Sustaining amplifier or so called TIA simulation result

Could someone point out where im doing wrong?

Comment: You have the output shorted to ground... that op-amp isn't happy. Not that SPICE simulates smoke ;)

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry, could you point out how to apply your advice to the circuit?

Comment: In fig.3, V3 defines Vo.

Comment: @TimWilliams I see, Is there any suggestion where i could place the impulse to start the circuit?

Comment: In series, or as a current to any other node, would likely work.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hey, I haved add a current pulse between the node of rm and lm. From the transisent response it start to oscillate but the amplitude is decaying. Is there a way to keep it at a certain amplitude?

Comment: Oh, and please add citation for where you got the source image(s) from (mainly fig1). What else; they have a TIA, they also show caps to GND either side of the resonator. You also need an op-amp with sufficient GBW.

Comment: Hi, I had added the source in following the descirption of fig1. The TIA in fig1 is the same concept of the sustaining amplifier that i am using in the simulation if it meets the following requirements: a) The gain is at least 1.5x larger than the rm of resonator. b) The phase shift pass the TIA or sustaining is 0 [degree]. In the sumulation, I am using an ideal op that has sufficient GBW and after adding caps to GND the output is still damping out.

Answer (score 0):

The loop should include an inverting gain stage. A positive feedback is required for oscillations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem was solved, I figured out that my circuit doesnt fullfill the barkhausen criteria.